# The output does not print the error message. It just continues to ask for a valid input instead of doing both

Tags: python, loops, binary

I'm still new to python. I have this code that asks for a binary number input. My code just repeatedly asks for a valid input rather than printing the error message too. How do I fix this? I'm using Python 3.

I've tried researching but the answers that i found does not fix my problem.

```
while True:
    try:
        firstdigit=int(input("Enter your first binary digit: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("ERROR: You must enter a binary digit.")
        continue
    if firstdigit in (1,0):
        break
clk=0
if (firstdigit==1) or (firstdigit==0):
    print("serial in: ",firstdigit)
    clk=clk+1
    print("serial out: ",0)
    print("parallel out: ",firstdigit)
    print('clk: ',clk)
    print("")
```

So far, this is what the output looks like:

```
Enter your first binary digit:5
Enter your first binary digit:3
Enter your first binary digit:8
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Enter your first binary digit: 5
ERROR: You must enter a binary digit.
Enter your first binary digit:
```

Comment: when you give input an integer it will not raise exception because you use int() outside input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just add an `else` part

```
while True:
    try:
        firstdigit = int(input("Enter your first binary digit: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("ERROR: You must enter a binary digit.")
        continue
    if firstdigit in (1,0):
        break
    else:
        print("ERROR: You must enter a binary digit.")
clk=0
if (firstdigit==1) or (firstdigit==0):
    print("serial in: ",firstdigit)
    clk=clk+1
    print("serial out: ",0)
    print("parallel out: ",firstdigit)
    print('clk: ',clk)
    print("")
```

Comment: @AubreyIllurimo You'e welcome, please vote-up and accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: your answer does not address for multiple binary digits

Comment: @TheScientificMethod It's because of the algorithm, the question was about printing errors not check binary numbers